# Was there any foreknowledge of the Paris hostage crisis within Judaism?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, current-events, prognostications

1. Did any school of thought within Judaism (like Kabbalah) predict the Paris hostage crisis?
2. Did any Jewish scholar make a prediction?
3. Are there any rumors about such a foreknowledge?

The question is referring to the
Porte de Vincennes hostage crisis on 9 January 2015:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte_de_Vincennes_hostage_crisis
Answers referring to the whole 'Paris attack' would be welcome too:
2015 Île-de-France attacks
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_%C3%8Ele-de-France_attacks
(this question is legitimate because, several websites claim, that the Zohar predicted the event of 9/11)

Comment: "Are there any rumors about such a foreknowledge?" *Now* there are. Good job, Andromeda. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

Despite the challenge involved in trying to prove that something isn't, I will assert that there were no specific predictions of the Paris massacre. The era of prophecy ended during the 2nd temple period. While there are instances of foreknowledge of events even nowadays, that is neither the norm nor considered to have special significance.

All the trouble we have encountered in our exile are predicted in the Torah in Parshas Ki Savo and Bechukosai. They are also described in detail in numerous places throughout the Prophets. In that sense, there are prophecies that describe the anti-semitic attacks that occur.

Comment: What about the Zohar predicting "children of Yishmael" destroying "twin towers"?

Comment: There are a lot of Zohars and Midrashim about the children of Yishmael. But they only get quoted after the fact, not before said even occurred.

Comment: Well, who really knows what's going to happen before it does? :P ....I agree with you, and honestly doubt that there's anything meaningful written about the Paris incident, but let's wait and see what turns up in the answers to this question ;-)